# Access Natural properties/method from User object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities mapped as follow:

```
 class Natural
{

    /**
     * @var \User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    ...
}

class User extends BaseUser
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     */
    protected $id;

    ...
}
```

What changes are need to made on `User` class in order to access `Natural` properties/methods as for example `user.natural.some_property` on a Twig template? Should I add a `OneToMany` relationship between `User` and `Natural` or which is the right way to get this?

**Test1**

I added this to `Natural` class:

```
/**
 * @var \User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="natural")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $user;
```

And this to `Usuario` class:

```
/**
 * @var \Natural
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\Natural", mappedBy="user")
 */
protected $natural;
```

Then in my template I try to access as `user.getNatural.getName` but I get this error:

> Impossible to access an attribute ("getName") on a NULL variable
>   ("") in FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig at line 4

I tried also this other `user.getNatural[0].getName` but get this other error:

> Impossible to access a key ("0") on a NULL variable ("") in
>   FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig at line 4

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is two-fold.

1. Yes, you need a OneToMany relation on User, maybe even a [bidirectional association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html) with mappedBy/inversedBy.
2. You can pass an entity as template variable and use it methods as twig functions/methods. Therefore, you should be able to do something like this in your template:

`{% for Natural in User.getNatural().getValues() %}
        {# do something with the Natural entity #}
    {% endfor %}`

Comment: `User->natural` should by default be an ArrayCollection object. You must assign this in the constructor (`$this->natural = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();`). Also, you should use getNatural as method, not as array (that means of course that you must write or generate the getter). And you must call the `getValues` method of the collection object to get an actual array to iterate over.

Comment: So having `user.getNatural.getName` I'll get an `ArrayCollection`? How do I access the `getName` property on the current recently created `User`?

Comment: Maybe you should first play around a bit with OneToMany associations in your code. I cannot start explaining everything about Collections and relations in an SO comment.